# pandas plot value counts barplot in descending manner

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe where i am trying to count the occurrence of each value.
I plot it as horizontal bar but cant get it to be sorted.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','A','A','B','B','C'],columns = ['letters'])

df.value_counts()

A 3
B 2
C 1
```

[image]

How can i get it sorted in a descending manner?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can do it by changing your plotting line like this

```
df.letters.value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind = 'barh')
```

Comment: This is good if you want to plot the largest bar on top. To sort the bar categories alphabetically regardless of their value counts, use `df.letters.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False).plot(kind='barh')`

Comment: unless I misread the question, it doesn't say anywhere that it is referring to alphabetical order but if so, you are right

Comment: Thanks for that, yes i wanted to sort by the values and not the names. sorry about the confusion.

Comment: why not `df['letters'].value_counts().sort_values().plot.barh()`?

Answer (score 9):

This might count as a bit of a hack, but try this:

```
df.letters.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False).plot(kind='barh')
```